# What gets modified? Confusions with "only" (basic categorical logic)

Tags: meaning, adverbs, modifiers, logic

While learning basic categorical logic, I came across the following sentences:

1. "All kitchens are places for eating"
2. "All kitchens are only places for eating"
3. "All kitchens are places only for eating"

What difference in meaning, if any, do 2) and 3) have?

Comment: See also: [ell.se]

Comment: Why do people insist on using English language as if it were solely logic-driven? They don't seem to acknowledge the vital role pragmatics plays: immediate and peripheral context is _vital_. Here, in (2), even the sense of 'only' is indeterminate in the standalone sentence. It could mean 'nothing more than / merely' or it could mean  'used for no other purpose than as'. And neither definition applies strictly here: kitchens are mainly used for the preparation of food. Pragmatics renders logical analysis unsound. // I'd not bother trying to work out meanings of poorly thought-out examples.